# Heteroskedasticity in regression with ARIMA errors

Tags: r, time-series, arima, heteroscedasticity, seasonality

It is suggested to use `auto.arima` with `xreg` in regression with ARIMA errors. Especially when dealing with multiseasonality with regressors, we can use Fourier terms plus dummies and complete with ARIMA errors.

However, `auto.arima` assumes homoskedasticity. After running `auto.arima` and determining optimal orders of ARIMA and the number of harmonics, I have tried to run the model step by step.

The regression model with Fourier terms and dummies shows heteroskedasticity. Is  the model still available? Should I necessarily correct for heteroskedasticity?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is very important to deal with non constant variance. Ruey Tsay published a paper on [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/for.3980070102/abstract) called Outliers, level shifts, and variance changes in time series.

Answer (score 1):

In case of heteroskedasticity ARIMA provides incorrect forecasts. One of the ways to fix it is to use GARCH model instead which treats heteroskedasticity as variance to be modelled.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350427/arima-conditional-heteroskedasticity suggests an orderly approach to selecting transformations .